# Issue with run docker image for Blazor WebAssembly App

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, blazor-webassembly

Can anyone please help me to create a docker file for blazor webassembly ?

I am trying to creating docker file for blazor webassembly.
I have checked many docs and I have tried with many docker files. Every time my docker image build successful but when I run that image at that time I am getting error like below

"It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: [https://aka.ms/dotnet-download"](https://aka.ms/dotnet-download%22)

I am using below code

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlazorDemo.dll"]
```

This is my build command and it's working fine

`docker build --tag blazordemo .`

Below run command I have tried and here I am getting error

`docker run --publish 8001:80 --detach --name blazortestapp blazordemo`

`docker run -p 8080:80 blazordemo`

**Note - Blazor WebAssembly target framework is .NET Standard 2.1**

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to answer the question, but I've been facing the same issue and after doing a lot of searching, I realized that blazor wasm serves static files, unlike blazor server.

In order to serve the static files you're going to need a server like nginx.

1. Add a nginx.conf file to the src directory of your project

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

2. In your Dockerfile replace the following lines with,

```
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlazorDemo.dll"]
```

```
FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

3. Build the image and start the container

```
docker build . -t <name>
```

```
docker run -p 8080:80 <name>
```

Your container will be served on port 8080. Hope this helps anyone that came here looking for why it isn't working.